# How can i make new UILabel's have the default color as black (instead of clear)

Tags: ios, ios4, uiscrollview, uilabel, uicolor

I want to use IB as much as I can. Therefore I want to drag UILabel from the Library palette to the UIView. When I do this, the UILabel is set to white (default). I want the default color to be Black. I know I can do this programatically but I am trying to avoid that.

The problem:
I created a UIScrollView. I set up the dimensions and then I am trying to add UILabels.

However the labels are all white text (annoying because I have to change the color property per label).

Is there a way to make all labels (new ones that are dragged from IB to the view) have a default text color of black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if the change is as trivial as changing the background color, and you want to change the default color, you must have hundreds (or at least dozens) of labels, which tells me that the real problem is somewhere else.

However, if you *really* want to do this, I can think of a few ways:

1. Subclass UILabel and override initWithCoder or in your subclass to change the color. Then change your labels' classes to point to your subclass, which isn't really easier than changing the color, and you won't even see the result in IB.
2. If this was any other UIView subclass, overriding drawRect in a protocol could have worked. To get it to work for a UILabel, you probably have to do the text drawing too, and you still won't see the result in IB. Just listing your options.
3. If you really want to see the result in IB, you can go crazy and create an IB plugin, which could be the definition of killing a fly with a sledgehammer: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/custom-views-in-interface-builder-using.html
4. Finally, you can wait for iOS 5 and UIAppearance. Check out "What's new in iOS 5?" if you're a registered developer.

Comment: Thanks, I am a registered developer. I'll look into it